# Click handler on jQuery Dialog header/title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-ui-dialog

I can't seem to add a click event handler to the Dialog header/title.

Something in jQuery UI seems to be overriding the click handler, any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

I'm binding it to the `ui-dialog-titlebar` class:

```
var dlg = $("#dlg_"+id).dialog({ ... });
dlg.find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

If I try `alert(dlg.find('.ui-dialog-titlebar'));` then it alerts me an Object. But if I do `$('.ui-dialog-titlebar').click(function() { alert("test"); });` then it works fine, but its not an option since I have a few dialogs.

**I found the solution, I've answered it as an answer below.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.. the ui.dialog-titlebar class is not child of the dialog reference. So I simply did `dlg.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').click(...)` and all seems to work just fine!

Thanks though.

Comment: Yes was just about to post this!  The jQuery UI dialog code puts wrappers **around** your `<div>` container, not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `live()` instead of `click()`. So where you would have had:

```
$('.ui.dialog-titlebar').click(function() {});
```

use `live()` instead:

```
$('.ui.dialog-titlebar').live('click', function() {});
```

Since jQuery UI will be adding elements to the DOM to create the dialog boxes they will not be selected when you make the initial selection for binding just after the DOM is ready.

Comment: I'm creating the click handler after creating the dialog. If I do $('.ui.dialog-titlebar').click(function() {}); right after, it works. But I want to apply it to a special dialog, I have reference to the dialog and I've updated my question on how I try to detect the click with the dialog ref.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
$(".ui-dialog").on('click','.ui-dialog-titlebar', function() {});
```

Note the above is general for all dialogs.

For specific dialog you can do that:

```
$(".ui-dialog").on('click','.ui-dialog-titlebar', function() {

    var d=$(this).next();

    if(d.attr('id')=='dialogIdHere'){

       //do stuff here

    }

});
```